# Border doesnt work on footer

Tags: border, footer

I have a problem. I want to have top border on my footer but it seems the code isnt working. I have searched on the internet for answer but aside from border showing somewhere different then footer on the page there is nothing on my problem. So i need your help on why is my border code not working? All other things on footer works perfectly. What am i missing here?

This is css for my footer:

```
footer{
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
width:100%;
height:60px;   
background: #404040 ;
clear: both;
border-top: 2px solid #FFFFFF;
}
```

If you need html too, tell me and i will post fiddle.
Edit1: here is fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/N8eJp/

Comment: Either post fiddle or add html + screenshot of how it looks

Comment: I have updated my post with fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Your border work, but it's difficult to see it. Try to change the color to #000 to see it black and to be sure it is working

Comment: On fiddle it works but if i change it in my editor and open it in browser it doesnt show

Comment: Have you tried to open it with chrome in developper mode. And then check in the Elements part if your css is apply or not

Comment: I did that and i tryed writing it in developper mode and it works, but when i put the same code that worked on developper in my editor and save it doesnt work anymore.